# Distributed JMeter tests with per-slave CSV datasets

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to run a distrubuted JMeter test on our site, following the 
[manual](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf). My tests are parametrized via a CSV DataSet configuration element to simulate diffent users. The question is now: Will JMeter use the same DataSet for each slave, or can I somehow configure each slave with its own dataset? If the first is the case, slaves will steal each other's session which is of course undesired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jmeter use local CSV fiels in distributed mode. So you just place different files on each slave and it works. Nothing special to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the CSV Data behaviour with the Sharing mode option. Description of each option detailed in:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config